# Is rails considered a rack application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm confused as to what is a rack application.

Is rails built on top of rack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails is built on top of the Rack interface.

More information about what makes a Rack application a Rack application can be found here: http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html